# . Find the projection of the triangle on the coordinate planes.

Tags: vector-spaces, analytic-geometry, triangles, 3d

Given the following, three vectors:
a⃗ =3i−2j+5k
b⃗ =i−6j+6k
c⃗ =2i+3j−k
Relative to cartesian coordinate systems with origin O.

I calculated the sides to be 4.58,11.45 and 7.87. I also calculated all angles to be 17.4∘,131.68∘ and 30.91∘ .

The last part of this questions requires me find the projections of the triangle on the coordinates plane xy, yz, zx,

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know what it means to project a shape onto a coordinate plane?

Comment: Thats my problem i dont fully understand the question. I understand that it is a 3d shape and by projecting onto the XY plane it will become 2d. Other than that i dont know were to go with this question.